# Cordova app iOS Warning: The app references non-public selectors in Payload/XXX.app/XXX: transform: (51)?

Tags: ios, cordova, app-store-connect

I've submitted an update of my app to ap store connect today and all of a sudden I'm getting this Warning:

`The app references non-public selectors in Payload/XXX.app/XXX: transform: (51)?`

The warning doesn't give any indication on whats causing this at all so I'm not sure what they are asking for or how to fix this!

any suggestion as to what this is?

I know this is just a warning at the moment and the app might pass the review but I need to know how to resolve this for future ref.

Comment: did you figure this out?